# Docummenting with react-docgen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There is some possibility to run react-docgen for file containing only export functions in react-native project.

I am using redux in my app and I have action and reducers files. They don't have class. They contain only functions and I want them, to be documented,

Thank you, for your response.